# The error that tells me in the console that an INTO is missing in the SELECT. PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

This query is in Oracle SQL developer, it is a stored procedure that can receive a value or number or the RUC and in the IF validating if a value is null search with in the SELECT.

Error:

> AN INTO CLAUSE IS EXPECTED IN THE SELECT SENTENCE

Query:

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Otc_sp_rpt_ips(par_ruc         IN VARCHAR2,
                                           par_facturacion IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    IF par_ruc IS NULL THEN
      BEGIN
          SELECT ca.legal_name   "Legal Name/Name",
                 vw.documento_cliente,
                 ph.name         "Phone Number",
                 vw.estado_abonado,
                 icc.iccid,
                 icc.imsi,
                 ip.name         "IP Address",
                 pi.created_when "Created When"
          --pi.object_id , pi.name, ca.type
          FROM   r_om_m2m_pi pi
                 join r_ri_private_ip_addr ip
                   ON pi.ip_address = ip.object_id
                 join r_ri_mobile_phone_number ph
                   ON pi.mobile_phone_number = ph.object_id
                 join r_cbm_billing_acct ba
                   ON pi.billing_account = ba.object_id
                 join r_cim_bsns_cust_acct ca
                   ON ba.parent_id = ca.object_id
                 join r_am_sim icc
                   ON pi.sim_card = icc.object_id
                 join otc_t_abonados_mov vw
                   ON ( vw.num_telefonico = ph.name
                        AND estado_abonado <> 'BAA'
                        AND vw.documento_cliente IN ( par_facturacion ) );
      END;
    ELSE
      BEGIN
          SELECT ca.legal_name   AS "Legal Name/Name",
                 vw.documento_cliente,
                 ph.name         AS "Phone Number",
                 vw.estado_abonado,
                 icc.iccid,
                 icc.imsi,
                 ip.name         AS "IP Address",
                 pi.created_when AS "Created When"
          --pi.object_id , pi.name, ca.type
          FROM   r_om_m2m_pi pi
                 join r_ri_private_ip_addr ip
                   ON pi.ip_address = ip.object_id
                 join r_ri_mobile_phone_number ph
                   ON pi.mobile_phone_number = ph.object_id
                 join r_cbm_billing_acct ba
                   ON pi.billing_account = ba.object_id
                 join r_cim_bsns_cust_acct ca
                   ON ba.parent_id = ca.object_id
                 join r_am_sim icc
                   ON pi.sim_card = icc.object_id
                 join otc_t_abonados_mov vw
                   ON ( vw.num_telefonico = ph.name
                        AND estado_abonado <> 'BAA'
                        AND vw.account_num IN ( par_ruc ) );
      END;
    END IF;
END otc_sp_rpt_ips;
```

---EXAMPLE----
`BEGIN OTC_SP_RPT('1790005739001',''); END;`
---EXAMPLE 2----
`BEGIN OTC_SP_RPT('','2874695'); END;`

Comment: In a PL/SQL block your SQL will have to do something with the SELECTed data...either use a cursor + record, or use some variables to receive the column data (for a single record query). Try defining some variables and then put "into v_legal_name, v_documento_cliente..." and so on right before the "from" clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the result of a select query from this procedure, You have to use sys_refcursor  as an out parameter in your code as Oracle cannot return results without that. So you need to use the below query -

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Otc_sp_rpt_ips(par_ruc         IN VARCHAR2,
                                           par_facturacion IN VARCHAR2,
                                           result          OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
    IF par_ruc IS NULL THEN
      BEGIN
          OPEN RESULT FOR
          SELECT ca.legal_name   "Legal Name/Name",
                 vw.documento_cliente,
                 ph.name         "Phone Number",
                 vw.estado_abonado,
                 icc.iccid,
                 icc.imsi,
                 ip.name         "IP Address",
                 pi.created_when "Created When"
          --pi.object_id , pi.name, ca.type
          FROM   r_om_m2m_pi pi
                 join r_ri_private_ip_addr ip ON pi.ip_address = ip.object_id
                 join r_ri_mobile_phone_number ph ON pi.mobile_phone_number = ph.object_id
                 join r_cbm_billing_acct ba ON pi.billing_account = ba.object_id
                 join r_cim_bsns_cust_acct ca ON ba.parent_id = ca.object_id
                 join r_am_sim icc ON pi.sim_card = icc.object_id
                 join otc_t_abonados_mov vw
                   ON ( vw.num_telefonico = ph.name
                        AND estado_abonado <> 'BAA'
                        AND vw.documento_cliente IN ( par_facturacion ) );
      END;
    ELSE
      BEGIN
          OPEN RESULT FOR
          SELECT ca.legal_name   AS "Legal Name/Name",
                 vw.documento_cliente,
                 ph.name         AS "Phone Number",
                 vw.estado_abonado,
                 icc.iccid,
                 icc.imsi,
                 ip.name         AS "IP Address",
                 pi.created_when AS "Created When"
          --pi.object_id , pi.name, ca.type
          FROM   r_om_m2m_pi pi
                 join r_ri_private_ip_addr ip
                   ON pi.ip_address = ip.object_id
                 join r_ri_mobile_phone_number ph
                   ON pi.mobile_phone_number = ph.object_id
                 join r_cbm_billing_acct ba
                   ON pi.billing_account = ba.object_id
                 join r_cim_bsns_cust_acct ca
                   ON ba.parent_id = ca.object_id
                 join r_am_sim icc
                   ON pi.sim_card = icc.object_id
                 join otc_t_abonados_mov vw
                   ON ( vw.num_telefonico = ph.name
                        AND estado_abonado <> 'BAA'
                        AND vw.account_num IN ( par_ruc ) );
      END;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error In Code');
              RETURN;
END otc_sp_rpt_ips;
```

From oracle 12C onwards there are few more methods to return the select query result also but you can still use this method.

Comment: You don't need most of those `begin...end` keywords. They aren't doing anything useful.

Comment: `when others then dbms_output` is kind of an an anti-pattern. You can improve exception handling by removing it.